# Is there an account to see all folders on a Time Capsule?

Tags: macos, root, time-capsule

When using Time Capsule with many user accounts, is there a root account to connect to the Time Capsule with, that can see all folders on the device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Username: admin
Password: [your base station admin password]

Note that your base station administrator password is often different from your wireless network password. It's the password you use to connect to the base station via the AirPort Utility, as opposed to the password you use to connect to the wireless network from the Wi-Fi Menu Extra.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a week!!! Thanks!